# What are sources for pathological and non-so-pathological Gabriel filters on commutative rings?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, universal-algebra

The heavy lifting in the theory of Gabriel filters is for noncommutative rings, and discussions I've been able to find all focus there.

I am trying to develop a theory of Gabriel-filter localization for Nikolai Durov's generalized rings, and some ugly classical examples would help.

Classical expositions seem to leap as quickly as possible to the associated torsion theories.  I doubt, after trying for a while, that torsion theories can work for modules over a GR:  Factor modules may be very badly behaved, even when the GR is "naive," with all operations faithfully represented on the monoid of unary operations.

Answer (score 2):

(It might look as if I got paid for promoting this book, but:) Bo Stenström's *Rings of Quotients* (Springer Grundlehren vol. 217, 1975; see [SpringerLink here](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-66066-5/page/1); an earlier draft had appeared as LNM 237) contains lots of examples of Gabriel filters (called Gabriel topologies there) on commutative as well as non-commutative rings. Of particular interest might be chapters VI -- IX and XIII, but all the chapters have many examples and exercises.